# Printing Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

This time I want to print an array from the end to the start.

This is what I wrote:

```
public class Arrays {
public static void main (String[] args){
    for (int i = args.length; i >=0; i--){
        System.out.print(args[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

and this is the error message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at Assignment02Q04.main(Assignment02Q04.java:5).

Still having a hard time to realize the Eclipse error notifactions.
I'll be glad for assistance.

Comment: I just want to mention that I input the array numbers in this form: 
{1 2 3 4}, in the Run configuration tab.

Comment: Arrays are zero based - shouldn't you start from args.length - 1 ? If the array has 4 entries its length will be 4 and its elements will be indexed 0, 1, 2, and 3

Comment: have you tried args.length -1? arrays are 0 based so array[1] is the 2nd element of it. If The length is 15, then the last element is array[14]

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of answers! Expert developers like your questions:)

Comment: @jzd: Why did you edit my "Hi" and "Thank you"? :)

Comment: @Nir avnon, see this question on Meta:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @Elijah: Perhaps that's because it is a clear, well-written question that can actually be answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In java arrays start with `0`. So an array of length 5 has elements with index `0 to 4`

The following statement

```
for (int i = args.length; i >=0; i--)
```

loops from `5 to 0` (for an array of size 5)

Change it to

```
for (int i = args.length-1; i >=0; i--)
```

and bingo!

PS: Actually you did loop till `0`, so you probably already knew that arrays start at `0`.

Answer (score 3):

Java uses 0 indexing for arrays, so your args.length needs to take that into account; you should start at one before:

```
for (int i = args.length-1; i >=0; i--){
```

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. You need to start with `int i = args.length - 1` since arrays are indexed starting from 0, and the last element of the array is always the length minus 1.

Answer (score 3):

Since your array starts at index 0, then the last element is on the position `args.length - 1`.
You are trying to acces the element at array.length, hence the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Just change `int i = args.length` to `int i = args.length - 1`.

By the way, those are not "Eclipse error notifactions", they are Java Exceptions :)

Answer (score 3):

.length of an array gives the count of elements in the array (starting at 1), but array indices start at 0, so the first iteration tries to access `args[4]` when the last element is actually `args[3]` and the size of the array is 4.

Change your code to:

```
for(int i = args.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

and you'll be fine

Comment: you're forgetting the -1 in args.length I believe

Answer (score 3):

You can access till the `(length - 1)` in an array

An array which is `{a, b, c}`,
a is indexed 0, b is 1, c is 2. Length is 3 but you cant access the array at the 3rd place.

Comment: You should try doing "Tohna 1" HW by yourself btw.

Comment: I tried to realize what's wrong without any sucesses. I am doing it on my own, no harm with learning from others.

Answer (score 3):

Array index starts at 0. So the last index is length-1.

When you have an array with 5 elements then the last has the index 4.

Your loop have to be

```
for (int i = args.length-1; i >=0; i--){
```

Answer (score 3):

Run your loop as (this is the foreach syntax)

```
for(String s : args) {
    System.out.print(s + " ");
}
```

instead. The array enumeration starts with 0 and ends with `array.length - 1`. The exception also tells you what was the element number when exception was raised.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to do your loop that way round, you will have to start at `args.length - 1`  Think about it like this, if you have an array with a single element length will return 1, and the only accessible index will be 0.  Base on your code you will start at index 1, hence the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 3):

Close! It's just this line:

```
for (int i = args.length; i >=0; i--) {
```

That needs to change to:

```
for (int i = args.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
```

Why? Arrays in Java (and most languages) start at 0 and end at length-1. So if you've got an array of length 3, the valid indexes will be 0, 1 and 2. The index at length 3 will be invalid and thus cause an exception, which is what Java is complaining about.

Answer (score 3):

In java array's indexes starts from 0.
For example args contains 4 elemens, their indexes will be 0,1,2,3, but agrs.length is 4. You trying to get element, that lies beyond the array.

```
int i = args.length - 1 // will work
```

Answer (score 3):

All the other answers are correct, but here is another way to do so in Java (same complexity order)

```
    List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(args);
    Collections.reverse(asList);
    for (String arg : asList) {
        System.out.println(arg + " ");
    }
```

It traverses twice instead of once, but if you need the array to stay reversed for later use, this is better

Answer (score 2):

You did args(args.length) thats invalid, you went to the place after the last in the array.
an starts at 0 and goes untill length - 1

Answer (score 1):

you starting from too high index:

just replace i = args.length with i = args.length - 1

ah i remember my tohna 1 second exercise :)